# How to forward a request to non-JSF page in action method?

Tags: jsf, navigation, forward

I want to forward request to a non-JSF page from JSF action method.
I am using below code in my JSF action :

```
public String submitUserResponse() {
    // ...

    parseResponse("foo.jsp", request, response);

    // ...

    return "nextpage";
}  

private String parseResponse(String uri, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (uri != null) { 
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(uri);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        return null;
    }

    // ...

    return "xxxx";
}
```

The `submitUserResponse()` action method is being called when user clicks the submit button from the JSF page and this method returns `nextpage` string. Here the request forwards to next JSF page in normal flow. But in my requirement, I need to forward request to next non-JSF page. It is going, but it is displaying below exception in server.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

I observed that code lines between `parseResponse(...)` and `return "nextpage";` are still being executed after forwarding my request using `dispatched.forward(uri)`. Same thing happened with `response.sendRedirect(url)`. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *Here my doubts are: 1.why next lines of code is being executed after forwarding my request using dispatched.forward(uri) . Same thing happening in response.sendRedirect("").*

Because you didn't call `return` to jump out of the method block. The `include()`, `forward()` or `sendRedirect()` really doesn't have some *magic* that they automagically does that. Those are still just Java methods like any other (except of `System#exit()` of course). They will be invoked in order and the code will just continue until end of method block or `return` statement. It's just all about the code flow **you** write and control yourself.

That said, the normal JSF practice is that you should use [`ExternalContext#dispatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#dispatch-java.lang.String-) or [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect-java.lang.String-) for this (the first is applicable in your case). Not only it keeps your code free from unnecessary "under-the-hood" clutter in JSF code such as the Servlet API, but it also removes the need to call [`FacesContext#responseComplete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete--) which you could also have done to fix your initial `IllegalStateException` problem.

In a nutshell: replace your code by

```
public void submitUserResponse(){
    String uri = "foo.jsp";
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch(uri);
}
```

That's all. No need to unnecessarily dig the Servlet request/response from under the JSF hoods. Note that the method is declared `void`. This is perfectly acceptable, although some know-it-better like IDE's will complain about it, if so, then just ignore it or replace by `String` and add `return null;`.

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [ExternalContext.dispatch() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163457/externalcontext-dispatch-not-working/)

Comment: I did samething . but i am getting same Exception message.
Here i want to redirect request to another application.
so i used 
    
    public String editVerismo_initAction(){
      ..........
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(redirectUrl);
return null;
}

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/ServletUrl");

(pay special attention to the fwd slash '/')