# Forwarding a request from a JSF managed bean to a Struts 2 action does not work

Tags: jsf, servlets, struts2, forward

Within a JSF managed bean, I have the following code taken from [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922154/jsf-how-to-forward-a-request-to-another-page-in-action/1922184#1922184):

```
String uri = "/myAction";
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch(uri);
```

`myAction` is the name of a Struts action that is defined in my `struts.xml`.

However when I access the JSF bean, I am not forwarded to `/myAction`. Instead I'm getting a 404 http error: `The requested resource (/MyApp/myAction) is not available`.

Why doesn't it work??

When I try to access `/myAction` directly from a browser by going to `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/myAction` all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the javadoc for the `dispatch`method:

"Parameters:
path - **Context relative** path to the specified resource, which must start with a slash ("/") character"

i.e it's dispatching to a url relative to your application context,not your webserver root folder

What you need is the `redirect` method which redirects to an absolute url.

Comment: Why does it look to you like the url I used (/myAction), in order for it to work, should be relative to the webserver root folder (`http://mydomain.com`)? It should be relative to the application context (`http://mydomain.com/MyApp`). And as you said, it is. So it should have worked, if I get you right. It does work with xhtml files, that are also found at the root of the application context, such as `/welcome.xhtml`. Did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: For some reason, I thought the source of the problem is that the JSF managed bean lives within a servlet (the JSF servlet), while the Struts action lives within a filter (the Struts 2 filter). And filters are called after all the servlets are completed. So it seems like if I forward from a JSF bean to a framework that is built around a filter, it cannot just work... since there is no filter yet as long as the JSF bean is alive. Or do I misunderstand the life cycle?

Comment: ahh, I'm sorry. the dangers of posting when tired. I saw "When I try to access /myAction" and thought you were not accessing via application context. In which case, yeah this is odd...but I haven't used struts so I don't know how struts filters should be accessed. the dispatch method though in the servlet api is expecting to land on another servlet I beleive (thats howI've always used them) -so I bet it is because the struts is a filter. Does using redirect work for you?

Comment: I believe redirect wold work, since under the hood it's just two separate requests, the second is launched by the browser. The problem is that after the redirection, I lose the previous request & response data. Any trick how I get out of this deadlock? When I submit a form, I must first let the request pass thru the (legacy) Struts action - then I need to somehow forward it to a JSF managed bean, in order to let JSF create the result view. I should submit the form by POST, not GET, unfortunately.

Comment: I have seen in the following thread https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=7185500#7185500 they suggest doing what I originally did: forward to the struts action from a managed bean (the guy seems to have a mistake in his 2nd code snippet). However I am not sure he actually tested it. It seems very "reasonable" for it to work, but it does not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Struts 2 Filter in `web.xml` to accept forwards (and direct requests (or redirects)):

In your `web.xml`, change:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

To:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <!-- uncomment if you plan to include struts action output -->
    <!--
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Credit:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/59584/Struts/request-dispatcher-struts-action

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm#BCFIEDGB